# What property can I use to find duplicate emails in a PST file?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I have several gigs of emails in a PST file.  There are many, many duplicates email items. I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library to access the emails in the PST file.  Is there a particular property of the email that acts as a unique ID that I can use to find duplicates.  I could compare the body, but this would not be efficient.

Comment: Well we do a very similar process in our software and we use Redemption (developed by Dmitry who posted below). The component is amazing and can process the content of PST in parallel which I believe isn't available in Office Outlook Interop (correct me if I am wrong please someone). Generate an MD5 using Subject, sent/receive date and body and you should be able to get your list of duplicates fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your definition of "duplicate"? Do you consider duplicate 2 emails with the same subject but different bodies? Same body/subject but different dates?

The exact de-duping algorithm will depend on what you consider a dupe.

Comment: Exact duplicates in archive.pst.  Somehow, Outlook archived the same emails dozens of times within the archive file.  I want to open the archive file, iterate through the Outlook.EmailItem objects and find the duplicates.

Comment: They cannot be exactly the same - for one thing, entry id, creation time, and last modification times will be different. If it was the same message downloaded from the same POP3 server, the message id (MAPI property name PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID) will be the same. The property can be accessed using MailItem.ProperyAccessor.GetProperty. The DASL property name is     http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F. Have a look at the messages with OutlookSpy first (click IMessage button) to make sure the ids are the same.

Comment: The link is no longer available.  Would EntryID be the same as well ?

Comment: This is not a link, this is a DASL property name (string) that you need to pass to MailItem.ProperyAccessor.GetProperty. Did you take a look at the message with OutlookSpy?

Comment: I will take a look at OutlookSpy and report back.